# Plot not working for a phase diagram

Tags: plotting

Whatever I have tried, I could not achieve to plot numerical values coming from my system of differential equation. 
It is a optimal control model with two state variables. My differential system is as follows ;

```
   dek = k'[t] == k[t]^α (r[t] s[t])^β - δ k[t] - c[t] - g k[t];
   des = s'[t] == -r[t] s[t] - (-rr) s[t];
   dec = c'[t] == c[t]/σ (α k[t]^(α - 1) (r[t] s[t])^β - δ - ρ);
   der = r'[t] ==  r[t]/(β -  1) (α  c[t]/k[t] - δ (1 - α)) + r[t]^2;
```

I use NDSolve to solve the system (I have calculated initial values in previous stages which are not relevant to my question) ;

```
soldif[t_] = with[{σ = 1.8, α = 0.4, β = 0.1, ρ= 0.02, δ = 0.05, g = -0.0029411764705882357,  rr = 0.017647058823529415}, 
NDSolve[{dec, dek, der, des, c[0] == 0.130567, k[0] == 0.167055, r[0] == 0.0157895, 
s[0] == 1}, {c, k, r, s}, {t, 0, 60}], 
Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "StiffnessTest" -> False}]
```

I define ;

```
  cb[t_] := Evaluate[soldif[t_][[2, 1, 1, 2]]]
  kb[t_] := Evaluate[soldif[t_][[2, 1, 2, 2]]]
  rb[t_] := Evaluate[soldif[t_][[2, 1, 3, 2]]]
  sb[t_] := Evaluate[soldif[t_][[2, 1, 4, 2]]]
```

Finally, I use the following plot command in order to draw a phase diagram on a plane (c,k) but it does not work ;

```
  tra1 = Plot[{kb[t], cb[t]}, {t, 0, 60}, AxesLabel -> {k, c}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.1]]
```

I have no idea why it does not work, any hints or suggestions ? Thanks so much.

Comment: If you want a phase plot, you should be doing `ParametricPlot[{kb[t], cb[t]}, {t, 0, 60}, <options>]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you used `with` when you should have used `With` and the assignments to `cb`,... won't work this way. Let me give you an easier alternative that uses `NDSolveValue`

```
With[{σ=1.8,α=0.4,β=0.1,ρ=0.02,
      δ=0.05,g=-0.0029411764705882357,rr=0.017647058823529415},
  dek=k'[t]==k[t]^α (r[t] s[t])^β-δ k[t]-c[t]-g k[t];
  des=s'[t]==-r[t] s[t]-(-rr) s[t];
  dec=c'[t]==c[t]/σ (α k[t]^(α-1) (r[t] s[t])^β-δ-ρ);
  der=r'[t]==r[t]/(β-1) (α c[t]/k[t]-δ (1-α))+r[t]^2;
]
   
{cb, kb, rb, sb} = NDSolveValue[{dec, dek, der, des, c[0] == 0.130567, 
    k[0] == 0.167055, r[0] == 0.0157895, s[0] == 1}, 
    {c, k, r, s}, {t, 0, 60}, 
   Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "StiffnessTest" -> False}]


Plot[{cb[t], rb[t]}, {t, 0, 60}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Some explanation

OK, the issue of your wrong `with` needs a bit of explanation, because when you simply replace it with `With`, it won't work after the next start of *Mathematica* (or Kernel restart).

What happens when you use `With` is, that it *replaces all occurrences of the defined variables with their value*. The important part is that it won't work if the variable is not explicitly in the code. Example:

```
ClearAll[a];
expr = a + a;
With[{a = 2},
 {expr, a + a}
]
(* {2 a, 4} *)
```

Note that only the explicit `a+a` is replaced but not `expr` which evaluates *afterwards* to `2a`.

Now, why did it work when you used `with` but it doesn't when you use `With`? Exactly for this reason. Assume you wanted to calculate the above expression and you mistyped `With` with `boing`. Let's see what happens and why it happens:

```
boing[{a = 2},
 expr
 ]
(* boing[{2}, 4] *)
```

You see your function `boing` is still there (because doesn't have a definition) but on the way of evaluating the arguments, you accidentally assigned the global variable `a=2` which is then used when `expr` is evaluated. Therefore, it is kind of the same as doing

```
a = 1;
expr
```

The conclusion to all this is that you need to use `With` where you really want to replace the parameters `alpha`, etc.. and this is in the assignment of `dek`, `des`, ... Therefore, I have put the `With` around this to make the replacement work.

Comment: Despite the fact that there is a `Plot` command at the end of the original post, I'm pretty sure the OP wants a phase plot, so probably `Plot` should be `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: @halirutan thanks for this clear and helpful answer. I think it could be easy to implement a phase diagram with ParametricPlot as march has mentionned above.